# Using Powershell Update XML Settings based on attirbute name

Tags: xml, powershell, attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <SystemConfig>
    <Setting name="Email---SmtpDebug">false</Setting>
    <Setting name="Setting-Email">true</Setting>
    <Setting name="Program--Debug--Application">false</Setting>
 </SystemConfig>
```

Based on above XML file as an example, in PowerShell I would like to find a setting by attribute name and update the boolean value in the XML file.

For Example if we need to turn on smtp debug, find setting by attribute name=""Email---SmtpDebug" and then change the boolean value to false.

Any help is appreciated. I am a newbie to Powershell.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with xml, it's probably best to handle it with xpath. Something along the lines of

```
$xml = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <SystemConfig>
    <Setting name="Email---SmtpDebug">false</Setting>
    <Setting name="Setting-Email">true</Setting>
    <Setting name="Program--Debug--Application">false</Setting>
 </SystemConfig>
'
$target = $xml.SelectSingleNode('.//Setting[@name="Email---SmtpDebug"]');
$target.InnerText='true'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another a way without XPath would be like so:

```
[xml]$x = @'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <SystemConfig>
    <Setting name="Email---SmtpDebug">false</Setting>
    <Setting name="Setting-Email">true</Setting>
    <Setting name="Program--Debug--Application">false</Setting>
 </SystemConfig>
'@
$e = $x.SystemConfig.Setting | ? {$_.name -eq "Email---SmtpDebug"} 
$e."#text" = "true"
$x.save([console]::out)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<SystemConfig>
  <Setting name="Email---SmtpDebug">true</Setting>
  <Setting name="Setting-Email">true</Setting>
  <Setting name="Program--Debug--Application">false</Setting>
</SystemConfig>
```